# Build and install singed apk on android?metro packager error when opened in app

Tags: android, apk

I am trying to install a signed apk on my mobile but it keeps failing. 
When I gradlew assembleRelease ,after I install the apk on my phone,the app keeps getting closed over and over before it can load.

Then I tryed

```
    react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js 
   --bundle-output 
   ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle -- 
   assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

and

```
  gradlew assembleDebug.
```

Then I get another error when I install the apk on my phone,saying that I am missing the development server.

```
  def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true


 def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

 android {
// because of firestore:
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
 compileSdkVersion 27

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    // ndk {
    //     abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    // }
    // because of firestore:
    multiDexEnabled true
 }
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
  }
 splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), 
  "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    }

 }
 applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal- 
release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + 
  defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

and the logs from the error :

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
 1 verbose cli [ 'D:\\node.exe',
 1 verbose cli   'D:\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
 1 verbose cli   'start' ]
 2 info using npm@5.6.0
 3 info using node@v8.11.1
 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
 5 info lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~prestart: womencare@0.1.0
 6 info lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: womencare@0.1.0
 7 verbose lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
 8 verbose lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: PATH: 
 D:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp- 
 bin;C:\Users\thanos\womencare\react-native-firebase- 
 starter\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 


 Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:
\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\;D:\Git\cmd;C
:\Program Files 
(x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform- 
tools;;D:\Microsoft VS 

  Code\bin;C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Local\Microsoft
 \WindowsApps;C:\Users\thanos\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:
 \Users\thanos\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Program Files 
 (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\thanos\sdk-tools-windows- 
 4333796\tools\bin
 9 verbose lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: CWD: 
 C:\Users\thanos\womencare\react- 
 native-firebase-starter
  10 silly lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native 
 start' ]
 11 silly lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 11  signal: null
 12 info lifecycle womencare@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: womencare@0.1.0 start: `react-native start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 11
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(D:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
 13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(D:\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid womencare@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\thanos\womencare\react-native-firebase-starter
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "D:\\node.exe" "D:\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" 
"start"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 11
22 error womencare@0.1.0 start: `react-native start`
22 error Exit status 11
 23 error Failed at the womencare@0.1.0 start script.
 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
 logging output above.
 24 verbose exit [ 11, true ]
```

Comment: What is the error message when the install failed? Use `adb install` to see the error message.

Comment: well the initial error was on my development server saying EPERM:operation not permitted , lstat C:\users\react-native-firebase-starter\app\build\generated\fabric. Then the error in my phone is the following: Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle.Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

Comment: Could it be  because I cloned react-native-firebase-starter-kit to setup a new app?(I did npm run rename though)